# How to ask each player if they want another card

Tags: c++, blackjack

Made a couple changes.. But still not working. Now what happens is if I Enter 'y' nothing happens program just freeze there, if i enter 'n', it continues the for loop.

Here's what I have so far. Players are represented by the lines of my array and their hands are cols. `Cardtab` and `CardHandTab` is the wchar representing the cards they have EX: 1♥ and the rest is analog array containing the values of each card.

Actually just realized they would all get a card no matter their answer since a do while checks condition after executing the code but that doesn't solve my problem..

```
void anotherCard(const wchar_t* CardTab[], int ValTab[], const wchar_t* CardHandTab[4][5], int ValHandTab[4][5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        char answer = 0;
        wcout << "Player" << i + 1 << "Would you like another? y/n" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            int x;
            do
            {
                x = rand() % 51 + 0;
            } while (CardTab[x] == NULL);

            CardHandTab[i][3] = CardTab[x];
            ValHandTab[i][3] = ValTab[x];
            CardTab[x] = NULL;
            ValTab[x] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the code into the while loop.

Comment: I.e. `answer` never changes once you enter the outer loop. So of course it will loop forever if `answer == 'y'` (which should be checked at the TOP, not the bottom, of the loop).

Comment: Not what you are asking, I just feel I have to point it out. `rand` is absolutely horrible in terms of distribution and quality. You should use the modern C++ [random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) facilities.

Comment: im using srand(time(NULL)); which for now is all i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 I forgot it needs a way to exit.. adding a break; fixed it 

   void anotherCard(const wchar_t* CardTab[], int ValTab[], const wchar_t* CardHandTab[4][5], int ValHandTab[4][5])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            char answer = 0;
            wcout << "Player" << i + 1 << "Desirez vous une autre carte? y/n" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
            {
                int x;
                do
                {
                    x = rand() % 51 + 0;
                } while (CardTab[x] == NULL);

                CardHandTab[i][3] = CardTab[x];
                ValHandTab[i][3] = ValTab[x];
                CardTab[x] = NULL;
                ValTab[x] = 0;
                wcout << CardHandTab[i][3];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use if() instead of while(). It's unusual / pointless to create a loop only force a break on the first iteration.

Comment: `x = rand() % 51 + 0;` will only give you 51 possible values (0 .. 50).